# Adding data before save in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Post hasMany Tag:
My form:

```
$form->input('Post.title');
...
$form->input('Tag.0.name'); //1st tag
$form->input('Tag.1.name'); //2nd tag
```

This works perfectly, but...

I create some fields `Tag.n.name`, and I want add each time one tag by `$this->data['Tag'][some_number]['name'] = 'all';`
Do not ask me why i want that, but tell me how i can add 'all' tag in my model to each Post?

This should get effect 4 INSERT sqls: one add post, and three: 1st tag, 2nd tag, all tag.

More explain: How add more tags without form fields? How add default tags? No input hidden, only pro solutions:)

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->data['Tag'][] = array('name' => 'all');
```

Put this either in your Controller before saving `$this->data` or in the Model's `beforeSave()` callback.